# How to prevent recursion with dependent observables

Tags: knockout.js

I have an issue with my KnockoutJS code that is creating an infinite loop.

Say in my view model I have a value that represents the number of people going on a holiday. This value is bound to a select list, so that a customer can change the number of people.

```
var viewModel = {
    selectedTravellerCount:  ko.observable(),
    travellers: ko.observableArray([])       
}
```

When the value of the select list is changed (i.e. the quantity of travellers changes) I want to show an array of select lists to allow the customer to input the age of each traveller.

I assume that I need to create a observable dependent on the `selectedTravellerCount` that renders in the UI.

```
viewModel.travellerCount = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    var tQ = this.selectedTravellerCount();
    alert("count:" + tQ);
        for (var i = 0; i < tQ; i++) {
        alert("adding");
        var t = new traveller();
        alert("a");
        t.Age = 18;
        alert("b");
        this.travellers.push(t);
        alert("added");
    }
}, viewModel);
```

This works OK when the page is first rendered. However, the first time the select list is changed, the dependentObservable function is repeatedly called and gets as far as the `alert("b")` line.

So, it looks to me that the traveller is being pushed to the travellers array, which is then causing function to run again, which then gets repeated ad infinitum.

However, I thought the function should only depend on the `selectedTravellerCount` value changing.

What am I missing?

I've also tried:

```
var viewModel = {
   selectedTravellerCount:  ko.observable(),
   travellers: ko.observableArray([])
   addTraveller: function (age) {
       alert(age);
       this.travellers.push({ age: age });
   }         
}

viewModel.travellerCount = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    var tQ = this.selectedTravellerCount();
        for (var i = 0; i < tQ; i++) {
            this.addTraveller(18);
    }
}, viewModel);
```

Comment: If you create a method on your view model that add an element to the `travellers` array then call that instead of the `this.travellers.push(t);` line - does it work?

Comment: @ipr - i tried that and it still goes into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a subscription instead of dependsObservable(). A dependsObservable is triggered each time the viewModel changes, hence the name. Adding to the travellers == changing the viewModel

take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/majorbyte/AgsZH/)

Subscriptions are described [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html), at the bottom.

Comment: Oh, I thought the dependsObservable would only be triggered if the data that was being observed in the function changed (this.selectedTravellerCount())

Comment: thanks for your example. Can I just ask how you can edit your example code to stop text boxes being appended to the existing collection and instead replace the entire collection of boxes with a collection the size of the input number.

Comment: I updated the example. (putting in a viewModel.travellers([]); )

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but I thought I'd add that the `push` function internally creates a subscription to the `observableArray`. This is obviously unexpected behavior and I've opened an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/403) for this.